# Subversion performance issue on Linux

Tags: linux, performance, svn

My developers is complaining our SVN is slow. This is the data they collected:https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmYUS.jpg. The SVN server is on Linux in Canada and developers using Cygwin on Windows in UK.

So far, I've tried:
1. Using svn protocol instead of https, no different.
2. Run the same command with SVN Windows client in Canada, no different.
3. Run the same command on SVN Linux server, the result is a lot worse, 250 sec to check out, comparing to 136. The CPU, memory and disk i/o all normal.

Any suggestion to move forward?

Thanks
Jirong

Comment: I would double check your disk i/o.  Running the command on the SVN Linux server running a lot slower clearly indicates resource starvation to me.

Comment: here is what I see last time, do you see any problem: http://i42.tinypic.com/ao6yau.jpg

Comment: Is your subversion repo on an NFS mount? Why is the automounter using so much CPU?

Comment: Well when you have a problem, and that problem involves any kind of network access a good generic thing to do is to start up tcpdump/wireshark on the client, server, or a device between and capture data.  Then examine the traffic.  Do you see any large gaps in activity between the client and server.  Do you see any errors?  Do you see any DNS timeouts.  Do you see any retransmits, etc.

Comment: Yes, your iowait is at 32% (3rd line in top).  That is telling you that 32% of the time the system is waiting on disk i/o to complete.  Try running `iostat -dmxN 5`.  That'll give you more information about the disk i/o and includes a percentage that'll show you roughly how much i/o you're using up.  That percentage is not 100% accurate, it's an estimation.  It should be close though.  Assuming we're not talking about a networked filesystem, if your iowait (in top) is more than say 5% you have an i/o bottleneck that's affecting your performance.

Comment: 1. @yoonix: The server was small (1 cpu, 1G), so I added 1 more CPU and make it 4G ram. Now don't see any resource constrain during the check-out: http://tinypic.com/r/15hea6w/5. However it's still the same slow.

Comment: 2. @yoonix: I found the reason why it's slow while doing the same checkout on server. I am checkout to my home directory which is on NFS.

Comment: 3. @TheFiddlerWins: Our SVN repository is in local disk on /var/svn, not NFS.

Comment: 4. @Zoredache: I just did a wireshark and here is the summary, do you see any problem? http://tinypic.com/r/2hfkfsw/5

Comment: You wouldn't see a problem from a summary.  You would want to look for things like DNS requests that timeout. Requests that take a long time to answer.  You look for redirects and errors.  Anything unusual really.  I know looking for unusual things can be challenging, when you don't know that 'normal' looks like though.  In that case you have to basically setup a test environment that works fine and perform captures so you see what a good capture should look like.

Comment: 5. @Zoredache: Another screenshot, I only see some of them, not a lot. http://tinypic.com/r/33lgow5/5  http://tinypic.com/r/2iiu6u8/5